# Rolling % of total in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I've a sample pandas dataframe as below:

```
|       id       |    success    |
|:---------------|--------------:|
|       1        |       0       |
|       1        |       1       |
|       1        |       1       |
|       2        |       0       |
|       2        |       1       |
|       2        |       1       |
```

For each group of id, I'd like to find out the rolling % of success. 
For id 1, first record success=0. So success % is 0. 
Next row success = 1. Hence success % is 1/2 ( 1 success = 1, 2 total records including previous row). 
Next row success = 1. So success % is 2/3 (2 success 1s, 3 total records).
the resulting table will be as below:

```
|       id      |    success    |    success%.  |
|:--------------|--------------:|--------------:|
|       1       |       0       |       0       |
|       1       |       1       |       50      |
|       1       |       1       |       67      |
|       2       |       0       |       0       |
|       2       |       1       |       50      |
|       2       |       1       |       67      |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a `groupby` then apply a custom function based on [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html), and [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), however, the last is only available for the groupby object, so another way is to [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) and use the new index as the counter:

```
df['rate'] = df.groupby('id')['success'].apply(
   lambda serie: serie.cumsum()/(serie.reset_index().index + 1)*100).\
   round(0).astype(int)

df.rate

# 0     0
# 1    50
# 2    67
# 3     0
# 4    50
# 5    67
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) with [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) as:

```
df['success'] = (df.groupby('id')['success'].cumsum()\
                   .div(df.groupby('id').cumcount()+1)*100)\
                   .round(0).astype(int)

print(df)
   id  success
0   1        0
1   1       50
2   1       67
3   2        0
4   2       50
5   2       67
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find the groupby method usefull here:

```
groups = df.groupby("id")


dataframes = []
for name, gdf in groups:
    # gdf is a group of ids  (a df)
    gdf['cumsum'] = np.cumsum(gdf['success'])
    gdf['count'] = list(range(1, len(gdf)+1))
    gdf['%'] = gdf['cumsum']/ gdf['count']
    dataframes.append(gdf)

df = pd.concat(dataframes)
```

don't forget to import the numpy library

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple way to do it, but how about the following

```
df['succcess_cnt'] = df.groupby(['id'])['success'].cumsum()
df['try_cnt'] = 1
df['try_cumsum'] = df.groupby(['id'])['try_cnt'].cumsum()
df['success%'] = df['try_cnt'] / df['try_cumsum']
df = df.iloc[:,[0,1,5]]
```